# Could not open codec 'libopenh264': Unspecified error

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I am using OpenCV to process videos for my research. I have Python 2.7 and OpenCV 3.2 versions installed on Windows 10. When I do background subtraction on a video in Python using OpenCV, it works fine and produces the output. However, when I try to save the background subtracted video, it throws this error:

```
warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:779)
warning: MAH00119.avi (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:780)
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x34363258/'X264' is not supported with codec id 28 and format 'h264 / raw H.264 video'

Failed to load OpenH264 library: openh264-1.6.0-win64msvc.dll
    Please check environment and/or download library: https://github.com/cisco/openh264/releases

[libopenh264 @ 0000000001f5bf60] Incorrect library version loaded
Could not open codec 'libopenh264': Unspecified error
```

I am processing MP4 videos. And I followed the instructions carefully while installing ffmpeg, like adding the bin's path to environment variables. I don't know what else to do. Stuck on this for three days now.

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 23):

The error message you are getting says that openCV can't load the H264 codec. H264 doesn't come by default with the default installation of openCV.

To add the H264 codec download 'openh264-1.6.0-win64msvc.dll.bz2' from https://github.com/cisco/openh264/releases/tag/v1.6.0.

Extract the file and move the extracted DLL to the same directory as your python file. OpenCV should now be able to find the DLL and load the H264 codec.

Note that in your error message, openCV is looking for the openh264-1.6.0-win64msvc.dll (failed to load: openh264-1.6.0-win64msvc.dll.bz2) which is what we have now provided.

Comment: Additional remarks for your answer: according to \sources\3rdparty\ffmpeg\readme.txt the binary file can be placed into global system path (System32 or SysWOW64) or near application binaries. Optionally you can specify full path via the environment variable OPENH264_LIBRARY (not OPENH264_LIBRARY_PATH). Unfortunately OpenCV doesn't use PATH when trying to load this binary.

Comment: OpenCV now requires OpenH264 1.8.0

Answer (score 0):

I read [here](https://github.com/Crigges/Prebuilt-LGPL-2.1-FFmpeg-with-OpenH264) that you can place the extracted OpenH264 DLL in the FFmpeg bin folder. It worked for me!