# Is there a way to cut frames from a video to reduce its size and duration?

Tags: python, opencv, video

I have a large set of videos that I need to process but a this is slow going since the processing involves running through the entire video at about 0.6FPS and the vast majority of frames have little change between them.

Is there some way I could sample the video say every two seconds and save this as another video cutting the framerate and duration in two? I am not worried about losing information by doing this, I would gladly cut a 10 minute video down to a few hundred frames. I do need it to be a video file however and not a set of images.

Comment: Yes, why not decimate the input? For example, in 10 frames, you only pick one and process it. Just ignore the rest of the frames. Every time you retrieve a frame from your video, you increment a counter. Process only a frame when the frame counter reaches a "decimation value". Clear the counter once you have processed the target frame and start over the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may solve it using `cv2.VideoCapture` and `cv2.VideoWriter` or using [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).

The solution bellow uses [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python).
I posted both OpenCV solution, and FFmpeg solution.

Solving using OpenCV:

- Open input video file for reading using `cv2.VideoCapture`.
- Open output video file for writing using `cv2.VideoWriter`.
- Read all frames, but write only every 10th frame to the output file.

Solving using FFmpeg:

- Solution is based on: [Selecting one every n frames from a video using ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/1274661/selecting-one-every-n-frames-from-a-video-using-ffmpeg), but uses `ffmpeg-python`.

The following example is "self contained" - generates synthetic input video file for testing, and executes the frame skipping on the generated input video.

Here is the code (example using `ffmpeg-python` is at the bottom):

```
import ffmpeg  # Note: import ffmpeg is not a must, when using OpenCV solution.
import cv2
import sys

out_filename = 'out.mp4'

# Build synthetic video and read binary data into memory (for testing):
#########################################################################
in_filename = 'in.mp4'
width, height = 320, 240
fps = 1  # 1Hz (just for testing)

# Build synthetic video, for testing:
# ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=320x240:rate=1 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -t 50 in.mp4
(
    ffmpeg
    .input('testsrc=size={}x{}:rate={}'.format(width, height, fps), f='lavfi')
    .output(in_filename, vcodec='libx264', crf=18, t=50)
    .overwrite_output()
    .run()
)
#########################################################################

# Open video file for reading
in_vid = cv2.VideoCapture(in_filename)

#Exit if video not opened.
if not in_vid.isOpened():
    print('Cannot open input video file')
    sys.exit()

# Read first image (for getting resolution).
ok, frame = in_vid.read()
if not ok:
    print('Cannot read video file')
    sys.exit()

width, height = frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]

# Get frame rate of input video.
fps = in_vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

# Create video writer
# 264 doesn't come by default with the default installation of OpenCV, but I preferred using H.264 (supposed to be better than XVID).
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972503/could-not-open-codec-libopenh264-unspecified-error
# (I had to download openh264-1.8.0-win64.dll)
out_vid = cv2.VideoWriter(out_filename, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264'), fps, (width, height))


frame_counter = 0

while True:
    # Write every 10th frame to output video file.
    if ((frame_counter % 10) == 0):
        out_vid.write(frame)

    # Read a new frame
    ok, frame = in_vid.read()
    if not ok:
        break

    frame_counter += 1

out_vid.release()





# Selecting one every n frames from a video using FFmpeg:
# https://superuser.com/questions/1274661/selecting-one-every-n-frames-from-a-video-using-ffmpeg 
# ffmpeg -y -r 10 -i in.mp4 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,10))" -vsync vfr -vcodec libx264 -crf 18  1_every_10.mp4

out_filename = '1_every_10.mp4'

# Important: set input frame rate to fps*10
(
    ffmpeg
    .input(in_filename, r=str(fps*10))
    .output(out_filename, vf='select=not(mod(n\,10))', vsync='vfr', vcodec='libx264', crf='18')
    .overwrite_output()
    .run()
)
```

- Note: The solution looses some of the video quality, due to decoding and re-encoding.

---

You may also try FFmpeg [decimate filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#decimate-1), if you are looking for solution that skips frames according to metrics calculation.